# An orbit of symmetric polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, operator-theory, symmetric-functions

Consider the ring of polynomials $R:=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,x_3]$. Define the operators $E, I:R\rightarrow R$ by $Ef(x_1,x_2,x_3)=f(x_1-1,x_2,x_3)$ and the identity $If=f$.

Let $\mathcal{L}:R\rightarrow R$ be the operator given by
$$\mathcal{L}f=[(x_1+x_2)(x_1+x_3)E-x_1^2I]f.$$

Let $1$ stand for the constant function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=1$ and $\mathcal{L}^2f=\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{L}f)$, etc.

> **CLAIM.** Experiments suggest that $\mathcal{L}^n1$ is always a symmetric polynomial in $R$. Any proof?

**EDIT.** This has found a resolution (see Pietro Majer's answer).

For example, $\mathcal{L} 1=e_2$ and $\mathcal{L}^21=e_2^2-e_1e_2+e_3$ where $e_1=x_1+x_2+x_3, e_2=x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3, e_3=x_1x_2x_3$ are the standard elementary symmetric polynomials.

> **QUESTIONS.** (EDIT) These did not find a definitive answer (apart from Brendan McKay's evidence and argument).
>
> (1) Are there other orbits of symmetric polynomials under $\mathcal{L}$?
>
> (2) Are there other non-trivial operators with similar property over $R$?
>
> (3) What about over rings of many more variables?

Comment: Hm, would be interesting to see what it does to the classical bases .. the elementary, the power-sums, Schurs, etc...

Comment: If you start with $e_1$ then $\mathcal{L}e_1$ is not symmetric, for instance.

Comment: I think it may be useful to reexpress $E$ using Taylor series, so that $E$ becomes an entirely local operator: $Ef = f - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2} + ... + (-1)^i \frac{\partial^i f}{\partial x_1^i} + ...$.

Comment: Is it still true that $\mathcal{L}^m(e_2^n)$ is generally symmetric?

Comment: You can start with a linear combination of polynomials in the orbit you have and that will form a different orbit.  But that's cheating.

Comment: @user44191: $\mathcal{L}(e_2^2)$ is not symmetric.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: We don't allow "cheating" in our show. :-)

Comment: What is a spectral decomposition of this operator? This is a common way to study the powers. May be, the people who study discrete Schroedinger operators [if we consider the variable $x_1$ as the main, your operator $\mathcal{L}$ is called so, I guess] know all what is needed here.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Shouldn't a spectral decomposition of $\mathcal{L}$ be equivalent to a spectral decomposition of $E$, which is seriously hampered by the unipotence of $E$ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I see no reason why should they be related. A diffetential analogue to think about is something like $f(x)\mapsto u(x)f'_x+v(x)f(x)$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Oops! You're totally right.

Comment: Can you prove the two-variable version? ($\mathcal{L} = \left(x_1+x_2\right) E - x_1 I$)

Comment: I think you meant to say $\mathcal{L}=(x_1+x_2)x_1E-x_1^2I$.

Comment: No, I didn't -- although that would be an interesting one, too. Mine would generalize to $n$ variables: $\mathcal{L} = \left(\prod\limits_{i>1}\left(x_1+x_i\right) \right) E - x_1^{n-1}I$.

Comment: OK, no, my two-variable version clearly does not work.

Comment: @Fedor: perhaps it is a good idea. To this effect, I added a tag for such group.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose $f(x,y,z)$ is symmetric (in the following, *symmetric* tout court always means "symmetric w.r.to the three variables $(x,y,z)$") . Then  $\mathcal{L}f(x,y,z):=(x+y)(x+z)f(x-1,y,z)-x^2f(x,y,z)$ is already symmetric w.r.to $(y,z)$, so it is symmetric if and only if it is symmetric w.r.to $(x,y)$, that is, after simplifications, if and only if $f$ satisfies the functional equation
$$(x-y)f(x,y,z)-(x+z)f(x-1,y,z)+(y+z)f(x,y-1,z)=0.$$

*Claim*: if both $f$ and $\mathcal{L}f$ are symmetric, so is  $\mathcal{L}^2f$. In other words, the space of all symmetric solutions to the above functional equation is $\mathcal{L}$-invariant.

*Proof:* According to the observation above, in order to prove the claim, we need to check that the following is identically zero:
$$(x-y)\mathcal{L}f(x,y,z)-(x+z)\mathcal{L}f(x-1,y,z)+(y+z)\mathcal{L}f(x,y-1,z) $$
and we exploit the symmetry of $\mathcal{L}f$ writing it
$$(x-y)\mathcal{L}f(x,y,z)-(x+z)\mathcal{L}f(y,x-1,z)+(y+z)\mathcal{L}f(x,y-1,z) $$
namely
$$(x-y)\big[(x+y)(x+z)f(x-1,y,z)-x^2f(x,y,z)\big]$$$$
-(x+z)\big[(y-1+x)(y+z)f(y-1,x-1,z)-y^2f(y,x-1,z)\big]$$$$
+(y+z)\big[(x+y-1)(x+z)f(x-1,y-1,z)-x^2f(x,y-1,z)\big]$$

$$=\big[(x-y) (x+y)(x+z) +(x+z) y^2 \big]f(x-1,y,z)$$$$-(x-y)x^2f(x,y,z) 
-(y+z) x^2f(x,y-1,z) =$$

$$=-x^2\big[(x-y)f(x,y,z)-(x+z)f(x-1,y,z)+(y+z)f(x,y-1,z)\big]$$

which is indeed zero, according to the initial remark, since $\mathcal{L}f$ was assumed symmetric.

Comment: This is quite interesting because it suffices to check only $f, \mathcal{L}f$ are symmetric. Cool. I'll check the details.

Comment: Based on Pietro's proof, we may ask: (a) is it possible for a non-symmetric $f$ we get $\mathcal{L}f$ symmetric? (b) can we identify all those symmetric polynomials $g$ such that $\mathcal{L}g$ is symmetric?

Comment: your proof seems correct, up-voted.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan Haglund et al uses a similar proof in Lemma 4.3.1: https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/ftp/jim-conjecture/nsmac.pdf

to characterize the image of an operator using symmetric properties of the input and output.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: Yes, there's a relation. Thank you.

Comment: The next step is to understand the restriction of $\cal L$ to this subspace.

Comment: Another way to see this is the following :
Let $S_{uv}$ be the operator that exchanges $u$ and $v$.
Then $[\mathcal{L},S_{xy} \mathcal{L} S_{xy}] = [\mathcal{L},S_{yz} \mathcal{L} S_{yz}] = 0$.
From this it follows that $S_{xy} \mathcal{L}^2 f = S_{yz} \mathcal{L}^2 f = \mathcal{L}^2 f$ if $f$ and $\mathcal{L} f$ are symmetric.

Comment: Am I seeing it right that you (Pietro) can replace "symmetric" by "symmetric with respect to $x $ and $y $" throughout your proof, and it will remain just as valid, proving what is essentially a more general statement (because symmetry with respect to $y $ and $z $ is clearly preserved by $\mathcal{L} $) ? So, essentially, you can treat $z $ like a constant?

Comment: Correct. I notice now that polynomiality is not used either ($f$ may be any function)

Comment: Careful with "any function": the "after simplifications" step involves dividing by $x+y$, which is okay if you are working with polynomials but not okay if you allow arbitrary functions.

Comment: That's true; say  the condition for a general $f$ reads "either $(x+y)=0$ or $(x−y)f(x,y,z)−(x+z)f(x−1,y,z)+(y+z)f(x,y−1,z)=0$; but then we may infer the same for $\mathcal{L}$ that is: "either $(x+y)=0$ or $(x−y)\mathcal{L}f(x,y,z)−(x+z)\mathcal{L}f(x−1,y,z)+(y+z)\mathcal{L}f(x,y−1,z)=0$", so the conclusion is the same.

Answer (score 7):

Noting Pietro's finite check, I can report that all symmetric polynomials $p(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ up to degree 18 inclusive such that $\mathcal{L}p$ is symmetric are linear combinations of $1,\mathcal{L}1,\mathcal{L}^21,\ldots\,$.

This strongly suggests that there are no others.

An observation that might lead to an elementary proof is that, up to degree 18, all polynomials $p$ such that both $p$ and $\mathcal{L}p$ are symmetric are uniquely determined by the coefficients of the powers of $e_2$ (i.e. the terms in the representation in the base $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ which have the form $c e_2^k$).

Comment: This is quite an intensive search and I tend to believe your observation "no others". Voting up! On the other hand, what do you mean when you said "... determined by the coefficients..."? From my comment above, $\mathcal{L}(e_2^2)$ is not symmetric.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan : For example, consider all degree 4 symmetric polynomials: $p=c_0 + c_1e_1 + c_2e_2 + c_{11}e_1^2 + c_{111}e_1^3 + c_{1111}e_1^4 + c_{13}e_1e_3 + c_{112}e_1^2e_2 + c_{22}e_2^2$. Then the equation $p=\mathcal{L}p$ has solutions $c_0 + c_2 \mathcal{L}1 + c_{22}\mathcal{L}^21$ only.

Comment: But, why do you equate $p=\mathcal{L}p$? Are you looking for eigenfunctions? Otherwise, we're trying to determine: given $q$ symmetric, is $\mathcal{L}q=p$ where $p, q$ are of the form you wrote. Are we not?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan : Sorry I mistyped.  I'm not solving $p=\mathcal{L}p$.  What I intended to write is that $\mathcal{L}p$ is symmetric iff $p = c_0 + c_2\mathcal{L}1 + c_{22}\mathcal{L}^21$.